# Sqlite different column names, but with same values

Tags: android, sqlite

Here is my current SQLite table:

```
CREATE TABLE formula (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,suggest_text_1 TEXT,formula TEXT,category TEXT);
```

I want to integrate search suggestions in an Android app, but I need a [`SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SearchManager.html#SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID) and I want my `_id` to represent it. But I also need a `_id` for the content provider. So is there a way where I could have [`SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SearchManager.html#SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID) and store the current and future values of `_id` in it? Would I use an alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would I use an alias?

This is possible but it depends on your exact requirements. See my answer to this question to see if this applies to you. [Android: column '_id' does not exist problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825020/android-column-id-does-not-exist-problem/5825507#5825507)

Comment: So basically what I want to do is to implement search suggestions in my application and I need the SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_ID so that I can call getData() on my search activity intent (android.intent.action.view). So I need that column in the database, and I want it to have the same values as _id. So how can I achieve that?

Comment: Yes use an alias. Something along the lines of `"SELECT _id AS " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID + " FROM table"`