# SQLite rename fts3 rowid column

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I'm using a tutorial [here](http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/11/android-autocompletetextview-sqlite-and-dependent-fields/) to provide an AutoCompleteTextView with a SimpleCursorAdapter. It works perfectly **as is**, but I've changed the database to use fts3 because I've heard it's faster (hence, the name).

It seems something in the code is hard-wired to use the column `_id` because after changing to an fts3 table, I get this error:

```
01-28 21:31:53.018: E/AndroidRuntime(16284): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
01-28 21:31:53.018: E/AndroidRuntime(16284): at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:314)
```

Even though I haven't declared the autoincrement key anywhere (as it's superceded by `rowid` in fts3). The error occurs in `AbstractCursor`, so there's not much I can do about it.

I'm thinking there might be a way to force the code to recognize `rowid` as `_id` by using `SELECT rowid,* FROM mytable` and then changing the column name somehow.. I'm pretty new to sql so any help is appreciated!

Comment: I have the exact same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming a column in SQLite can be done as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805363/how-do-i-rename-a-column-in-a-sqlite-database-table). Note that it is highly advisable to do all these operations in transaction. One detail when you are doing this in Android - I don't know how you execute sql scripts in your solution, but keep in mind [this](http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.com/2010/01/creating-multiple-sqlite-database.html) if you use execSQL calls.

By the way if you prefer not to rename the column you can try the technique proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5825507/1108032).

Comment: Your second suggestion (using `as`) worked without a hitch. Thanks!