# Why is my ListAdapter for android not working? 

Tags: android, cursor, listadapter

I am trying to get info from a database to a listadabter. 
Here is my code for getting the information to the layout:

```
    Cursor c = mnDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(c);
   String[] columns = new String[] {EquationsDbAdapter.KEY_VALUE};
   int to[] = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};
   SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,c , columns , to);
   setListAdapter(adapter);
```

My error is given by LogCat as :`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist`
 I have seen some other questions and tutorials and none of those seem to solve my problem. I don't even have a column in my database for _id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because SimpleCursorAdapter needs a field returned called "_id", though it doesn't have to be an actual name of a column in your table, but could be an alias.  There's a few threads here on SO talking about this, such as:

[Android: column '_id' does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825020/android-column-id-does-not-exist-problem)

[Android column '_id' does not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359414/android-column-id-does-not-exist)