# How to Query from 2 tables in a (Simple)CursorAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite

On a single table I do it like this:

```
public static String[] FROM_Benzinarii_onList = {DBConstants.Denumire_Benzinarie, DBConstants.Adresa, DBConstants.Distance, _ID};

public Cursor getStations_List(){
        db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        return db.query(DBConstants.TABELA_BENZINARII, FROM_Benzinarii_onList, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Then construct the adapter:

```
int[] values = {R.id.tv_benzinarie,R.id.tv_adresa,R.id.tv_dist}
Cursor cursor = getStations_List();
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.item_list, cursor,FROM_Benzinarii_onList, values);
     setListAdapter(adapter);
```

But now I need an extra colum, with price, from another table, and I am unable to obtain a cursor. I have tried the code below, and many others.

```
public static String[] FROM_Benzinarii_onList = {DBConstants.Denumire_Benzinarie, DBConstants.Adresa, DBConstants.Distance, DBConstants.Pret, _ID};

public Cursor getStations_List(){
        db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        String sql = " select " + DBConstants.TABELA_BENZINARII + "." + DBConstants.Denumire_Benzinarie + "," + DBConstants.TABELA_BENZINARII + "." + DBConstants.Adresa 
                + "," + DBConstants.TABELA_BENZINARII + "." + DBConstants.Distance + "," + DBConstants.TABELA_PRETURI + "." + DBConstants.Pret 
                + " from " + DBConstants.TABELA_PRETURI + "," + DBConstants.TABELA_BENZINARII
                + " where " + DBConstants.TABELA_BENZINARII + "." + DBConstants.ID_Benzinarie + " = " + DBConstants.TABELA_PRETURI + "." + DBConstants.ID_Benz;
        return db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    }
```

Then construct the SimpleAdapter in the same way (I don't know if it is correct !?)

```
int[] values = {R.id.tv_benzinarie,R.id.tv_adresa,R.id.tv_dist,R.id.tv_pret};

Cursor cursor = getStations_List();

SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.item_list, cursor,FROM_Benzinarii_onList, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

I get:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
```

I don't know if my new cursor has anything to do with `FROM_Benzinarii_onList` but I couldn't use `db.query` here
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer [Android column _id does not exist problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825020/android-column-id-does-not-exist-problem/5825507#5825507)

Try using an `alias` such as `select oid as _id...` as in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely need an _id column in your result Cursor to use it in a (Simple)CursorAdapter

Comment: Ok, but how can I do it? I specified it in the results String array, but it seems that has nothing to do with the cursor

Comment: In your String[], there is a element named _id. it must be present in the cursor. Therefore, it must be present in the SELECT.